# How to programmatically click an element with MooTools?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mootools, mootools-events

In jQuery, I've done stuff like this in the past:

```
$('#someCheckbox').click();
```

And everything works as if the user just clicked on the element normally. 
However the same doesn't work in MooTools:

```
$('someCheckbox').fireEvent('click');
```

The checkbox doesn't get checked, nor do any of the bound event handlers fire.

Is there a way to do this?
I need the already bound "click" event handlers to fire, so just setting it's "checked" attribute isn't an option.

Comment: does $('someCheckbox').onclick() work?

Comment: Firefox says: element.onclick is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click event should fire when `fireEvent('click')` is called. See http://mootools.net/shell/8bbgn/ for a demo I just set up.

The checkbox doesn't get checked, as expected. To do this, you must set the checked property to true:

```
$('someCheckbox').setProperty('checked', true);
```

Comment: Hmm.. well that definitely proofs the concept. But for some reason it's not working in my code. The handlers just don't fire. I'll have to debug some more...

Comment: Ok crap, between it not checking the box, and the event handler requiring the box to be checked to do anything, all lead me to believe this wasn't working as expected. But all good now thanks for double checking